# How to load both jquery and jquery-ui dynamically in an external script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Very inexperienced javascript/jquery/AJAX here; I've tried probably two dozen approaches to make this work, and I'm at a total loss.

I have developed a js widget and am loading jquery if it is not present.  That works well, as far as I can tell.  Unfortunately, as part of the main function, I use some functionality from jquery.ui.

I know that I have to load jquery first, but how can I extend the script below to also load jquery.ui, if it isn't present?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
(function() {

// Localize jQuery variable
var jQuery;

/******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '3.3.1') {
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src",
        "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js");
    if (script_tag.readyState) {
      script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
          if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
              scriptLoadHandler();
          }
      };
    } else {
      script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
    }
    // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
} else {
    // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
    jQuery = window.jQuery;
    main();
}

/******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
function scriptLoadHandler() {
    // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
    // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
    jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);

    // Call our main function
    main();
}

/******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
function scriptLoadHandler() {
    // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
    // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
    jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);

    // Call our main function
    main();
}

/******** Our main function ********/
function main() { 
//main functionality here
}
```

Comment: Most plugins will say "jQuery required" rather than providing it; more on making a jQuery plugin here: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/. You don't want your plugin loading anything else than what it absolutely needs to function.

Comment: That's helpful.  I obviously have a lot to learn.  Thanks for responding.

Comment: don't be hard on yourself you're doing more than I have - I've never created a plugin.

Comment: I agree with @NathanielFlick on this.  It's better to simply toss an error for anything web-based requiring additional dependencies.  It could be hosted somewhere offline and it's probably best to allow the end-user the ability to juggle different versions.